# react constructor-like in functional component

Tags: reactjs

With react hooks now we can have state in a functional component, so i tried rewriting a small project i had previously written using class components, in the process I encountered a problem that I might have an explanation for but i want to be sure.

**Brief overview**

So in my `App.js` component i fetch data then pass it as props to a list component that renders the data in steps, First it displays 4 items then as you scroll more gets added.

The way i did that is, the api gives me an array of 30 items, i pass all of it to a `list` component where i have an underlying array that i keep pulling from items and update the state so it renders.

**Example code**

```
class List extends Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.underlyingArray = [];
        this.state = {
            visibleList: []
        }
    }
    componentDidUpdate() {
        // checks if we have data 
        // populates the underlyingArray only if it's empy
    }

    render() {
        return this.state.visibleList
    }
}
```

In the constructor i initialize the `underlyingArray` to be empty then i populates it onces there's data.

---

Now when i tried converting all that to a functional component the `underlying array` keeps getting cleared or initialized every time there's a state change

**Example code**

```
const List = (props) => {
    let underlyingArray = [];
    let [visibleList, setVisibleList] = useState([])

    useEffect(() => {

        // checks if we have data 
        // populates the underlyingArray only if it's empy

    }, [props.data]); // runs the above code when we receive data from the api call

    return visibleList;
}
```

So i tried putting a `console.log()` at the top of the function and found out that whenever there's a state change i see that logging message so i looked up a solution for this and found some answers on SO suggested using the `useRef()` hook which works.

However this made question performance issues if i have several calls to functions that do some housekeeping stuff at the top thinking that i will only run once, and since hooks came to enable the use of state in a functional component, where's the constructor-like functionality ?

So, Is there a `constructor-like functionality` to initialize the component besides using `useRef()` because if it's supplied a function it'll still run on every render.

Comment: No, there's no constructor. But there are way to lazily initiate the state ( https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#lazy-initial-state ) and other tricks can be apply to improve performance. That's some kind of mental shift that you need to do moving from class-based component. In your case, yes, transform the `underlyingArray` to `useRef`, and add another `useEffect` that will run on mount and umount only ( keep the deps as an empty array ), and you can run the function inside it. It will ran only once.

Answer (score 18):

You can pass an empty array as the second argument of `useEffect`:

```
useEffect(() => {
  // Some initialization logic here
}, []);
```

That way the effect will be used only when the component is mounted or unmounted.

Comment: The idea is to have a local private variable inside the component, will i be able to access variables declared inside `useEffect()` ? I don't think so

Comment: If empty array is passed to the `useEffect`, you can still use `setState()` inside it because it will not cause rerender.

Comment: If you're suggesting to use state same as the other answer, Then How `useEffect()` is relevant then ? I will be accessing that variable from other functions within the component which would cause a re-render

Comment: Maybe variable declared via `useRef` and setting its value in this `useEffect` call?

Answer (score 4):

You can use `useMemo` to demonstrate as constructor for functional component. Some people suggested to use `useEffect` BUT it will be invoked after render.

```
useMemo(() => {
  console.log('This is useMemo')
}, []);
```

Answer (score 1):

Functional component execute all the lines of code in each call so your first line of code is executed in each "renderings/calls" of your component.

If your `underlyingArray` variable have to keep its values between all calls, you have to use `useState(initialValue)` hook. The `initialValue` is attributed on mounting before first rendering (like constructor).

A functional component is executed like a javascript function so all constants declared in the function don't persist after the return.

The useEffect doesn't work like a constructor method of class component because the constructor is called before the first rendering, while the useEffect with empty array in dependencies is called after the first return (and the return function of this useEffect before "unmounting" of the component).

You have to rebuild another logic with hooks :

1 - Create the state of visibleList and underlyingArray :

```
let [visibleList, setVisibleList] = useState([]);
let [underlyingArray, setUnderlyingArray] = useState([]);
```

2 - Make your logique in useEffect :

```
useEffect(()=>{
//Update underlyingArray if you have to
//Update visibleList if you have to
},[props.data]);
```

Don't add an empty array in dependencies of your useEffect function because you have to check if you want to update the visible array in each changes of props ???

Comment: If you turn the `underlyingArray` into a state any change to it would cause a re-render, and i edit it several times. Doesn't seem like a good solution to me.